# Hide Firebase FCM service worker key

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase FCM tokens, and I want to hide key values ​​from the service worker. But environment variables are not applied... Please tell me the solution

I want to receive payload through onMessage function.

This is my current code

```js
// public/firebase-messaging-sw.js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

// 이곳에 아까 위에서 앱 등록할때 받은 'firebaseConfig' 값을 넣어주세요.
const config = {
  apiKey: "value you want to hide",
  authDomain: "value you want to hide",
  projectId: "value you want to hide",
  storageBucket: "value you want to hide",
  messagingSenderId: "value you want to hide",
  appId: "value you want to hide",
  measurementId: "value you want to hide"
};
 
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(config);
 
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log("받은 푸시 데이터를 처리해 알림으로 띄우는 내용")
});
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  console.log("띄운 알림창을 클릭했을 때 처리할 내용")
});
```

```js
// /src/components/Message.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { messageState } from '@/libs/recoilState';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging, getToken, onMessage } from 'firebase/messaging';
import { useRecoilState } from 'recoil';

export interface MessageType {
  title: string;
  reservationId: string;
  description: string;
  [key: string]: string;
}

const Message = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useRecoilState<MessageType>(messageState);
  const onMessageFCM = async () => {
    const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
    if (permission !== 'granted') return;

    const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
      apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
      authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
      projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
      storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
      messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_ID,
      appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID,
      measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENT_ID,
    });

    const messaging = getMessaging(firebaseApp);

    getToken(messaging, {
      vapidKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY,
    })
      .then((currentToken) => {
        if (currentToken) {
          console.log(currentToken);
        } else {
          console.log(
            'No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.',
          );
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
      });

    onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
      console.log('Message received. ', payload); // I'm trying to get data from here.
      setMessage(payload?.data as MessageType); 
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onMessageFCM();
  }, []);

  return <></>;
};

export default Message;
```

I thought the config code was redundant, so I deleted the service worker's Firebase config code, but the onMessage function did not occur.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the Firebase config file or object is considered public, so it's okay to include it in your client code. See this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object) for your reference.

You may use the Security Rules feature of Database, Firestore or Storage to secure your data and files. On the other hand, if you wish to limit the access to the backend services in your project to those coming from registered apps, use App Check.

Other similar posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52101801/6523173
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484053/6523173